# Crack in concrete floor slab

Tags: foundation, cracks

I recently pulled up carpet/padding and discovered a foundation crack. It looks to be larger on one end. It appears to be slightly horizontal, about less than 1/2 inch at it's largest end. The foundation is poured concrete, no basement. The house was built back in 2009 and is located in FL. There are no recorded sinkholes in the area. It's the only crack in the house and seems to be localized to one side. I've noticed a slight tilt in the door frame (that's always been there) located next to the crack.
My question is: Is this something to be concerned about? Do I need to call a company to come in and evaluate it, or should I just keep an eye on it? [image][image]

Comment: That's not your foundation. It's your floor slab (which may be integral, but that's not really important). Please search the site for many similar questions.

Answer (score -1):

This is typical and poses no danger.  It's just a superficial crack in the floor slab.  I suspect if you remove more carpeting, you'll find more.

The biggest concern is that sometimes insects (like ants) can find their way up through these and start invading your home.  I'd seal it with some silicone caulk to prevent insect infiltration.

Other than that, as long as it doesn't start opening up more you should be OK.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?